# Angular Jest Spectator - focus function does not work

Tags: angular, jestjs, spectator

So, I have Angular component that looks like this

```
<div class="hello" (keydown.enter)="doSomething()"></div>
```

and I'm trying to write test for case - when user is focused in div, pressing enter should call doSomething(). Unfortunately, I cannot mock this situation with Spectator.
I've already tried:

```
spectator.focus(spectator.query('.hello'));
expect(spectator.query('.hello')).toBeFocused(); // test failed
spectator.keyboard.pressEnter();
```

also

```
spectator.query('.hello').dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
```

and both also with

```
spectator.detectChanges(); // without success
```

I suppose, that problem is in my HTML template, but those functions does not work also with:

```
<div class="hello" tabindex="0">
```

and even with

```
<input class="hello" type="text">
```

Please gimmie some support, how to focus on div element and then press enter on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to understand what `spectator.focus()` method does.

Let's take a look at this method in [Spectator source code](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator/blob/26517a489cb78d7bd7ddfc952feb8e744f8ee88c/projects/spectator/src/lib/base/dom-spectator.ts#L149-L157):

```
public focus(selector: SpectatorElement = this.element): void {
    const element = this.getNativeElement(selector);

    if (!(element instanceof HTMLElement)) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot focus: ${selector} is not a HTMLElement`);
    }

    patchElementFocus(element);
    element.focus();
    this.detectChanges();
}
```

We can notice that before triggering native `element.focus()` method it also calls `patchElementFocus(element);` Here's [the code](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator/blob/26517a489cb78d7bd7ddfc952feb8e744f8ee88c/projects/spectator/src/lib/internals/element-focus.ts#L10-L13) of this method:

```
export function patchElementFocus(element: HTMLElement): void {
  element.focus = () => dispatchFakeEvent(element, 'focus');
  element.blur = () => dispatchFakeEvent(element, 'blur');
}
```

where `dispatchFakeEvent` calls `node.dispatchEvent(event);` native method under the hood.

So, `spectator.focus(element)` triggers `node.dispatchEvent(...)`.

Now, you need to understand difference between trusted and untrusted events.

**Events fired by using node.dispatchEvent are called untrusted events and they do not trigger default browser actions** ([w3.org reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#trusted-events))

That means that **manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event**. For example, **manually firing a focus event does not cause the element to receive focus**, manually firing a submit event does not submit a form.

You can only listen to that manually created events through events handlers.
This is what Spectator demonstrates us. (Test https://github.com/ngneat/spectator/blob/fcdb6a809571706fac3d7b5d8da5bf2f7ba0e305/projects/spectator/test/events/events.component.spec.ts#L13) (Listener https://github.com/ngneat/spectator/blob/fcdb6a809571706fac3d7b5d8da5bf2f7ba0e305/projects/spectator/test/events/events.component.html#L2)

Finally, the solution here is to use native `element.focus()` method to be able to set focus on your div. Also, `tabindex attribute` is required here.

```
spectator.query<HTMLDivElement>('.hello').focus();
expect(spectator.query('.hello')).toBeFocused();
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-spectator-dpgkix?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer

Comment: Excellent answer. Also, I have [fixed spectator's focus patch](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator/blob/991118811d6f98570a97696e6bf9e18a91871797/projects/spectator/src/lib/internals/element-focus.ts#L57) so it always calls the `element.focus()`, and also sends a fake event if a real one isn't detected - some browsers don't send focus events when the browser window isn't in view. So, this workaround shouldn't be required any more (8.0.3 and later).